# Sphero MFi Verification

Tags: ios, mfi, sphero-api

we were submitting our app which uses Sphero SDK and the app got rejected. The app was made for big music festival where people can borrow Sphero and play with it for a while. Sadly, our app got rejected because of MFi Program Authorization. Is there anything we can do about it? We know that Sphero has this verification, we just don't know how to provide it to Apple.Heres full Apple Description why our app got rejected :

> ----- MFi - Program Authorization -----
>
> We are unable to post your app to the App Store at this time because
>   we have no verification that you are authorized to distribute apps
>   that interact with the required MFi hardware.
>
> Please work with the required hardware vendor to contact the
>   appropriate MFi account specialist to provide the necessary
>   verification.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

We need to authorize your app so Apple will approve it. Email support@gosphero.com and explain the above, ask that the issue be forward to Ross and Jon.